# Microsoft Graph API: Not receiving new message in mailbox notification

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, outlook-restapi

We have a system that implemented a function to use for tracking new messages (mail) that come to from users's Inbox and Sent email as well.

Our implementation is following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0. Microsoft system will push a notification (include mainID) when any new things in mailbox of user.

During development and testing with few message, we completely get notification from Microsoft to our webhook URL directly (like realtime).

The problem is introduced when to come production enviroment, our system usualy get 500-3000 emails per day, maybe more because number active user can be increased, we found that we sometimes missed few email-notifications from Microsoft to our webhook.

Is there any problem with Microsoft side since many newly email come? Any reason why they don't send enough email notificaiton to our webhook URL.

If so, any solution to help us for making sure we won't lost any newly email from user? Our customer complains that they can't see enough email information from their mailbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code is setup but one frequent pitfall is that the service can send you multiple notifications in a single HTTP request as documented in the link below. This especially happens with high volume of users and/or data updates. Can you check your implementation and see if it accounts for this aspect?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-example